# Regular expressions - Matching whitespace

Tags: regex, compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lex, lexical-analysis

I am having a big problem to write a regexp that will trim all the whitespace in my input.

I have tried `\s+` and `[ \t\t\r]+` but that don't work.

I need this because I am writing a scanner using flex, and I am stuck at matching whitespace.
The whitespace should just be matched and not removed.

Example input:

```
program 
3.3 5 7 
{ comment }
string
panic: cant happen
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. `flex` uses (approximately) the POSIX "Extended Regular Expression" syntax -- `\s` doesn't work, because it's a Perl extension.
2. Is `[ \t\t\r]+` a typo?  I think you'll want a `\n` in there.

Something like `[ \n\t\r]+` certainly *should* work.  For example, this lexer (which I've saved as `lexer.l`):

```
%{

#include <stdio.h>

%}

%option noyywrap

%%

[ \n\t\r]+  { printf("Whitespace: '%s'\n", yytext); }
[^ \n\t\r]+ { printf("Non-whitespace: '%s'\n", yytext); }

%%

int main(void)
{
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

...successfully matches the whitespace in your example input (which I've saved as `input.txt`):

```
$ flex lexer.l
$ gcc -o test lex.yy.c
$ ./test < input.txt
Non-whitespace: 'program'
Whitespace: ' 
'
Non-whitespace: '3.3'
Whitespace: ' '
Non-whitespace: '5'
Whitespace: ' '
Non-whitespace: '7'
Whitespace: ' 
'
Non-whitespace: '{'
Whitespace: ' '
Non-whitespace: 'comment'
Whitespace: ' '
Non-whitespace: '}'
Whitespace: '
'
Non-whitespace: 'string'
Whitespace: '
'
Non-whitespace: 'panic:'
Whitespace: ' '
Non-whitespace: 'cant'
Whitespace: ' '
Non-whitespace: 'happen'
Whitespace: '
'
```

Comment: Yes I meant \n instead of to t:s in [ \t\t\r]+ Thanks for your answer, its correct :)

Comment: Use `[ \n\t\r\f]+ ` for matching all line ending. Omitting `\f` won't match Windows/DOS file endings.

Source: http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~bvz/cs461/notes/flex/

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a specialist in flex, but have you should use /g and /m flags in your regular expression, to work with multiline srings.